# How to write - with diaresis in ConTeXt

Tags: context

I would like to know how to place a diaresis above a minus or hyphen:

```
\"{a}
```

would give ä but how to get the equivalent of

```
\"{–}
```

as needed for typing german language-learner texts?

Comment: You could do $\ddot{-}$. I'm guessing that the LuaTeX engine underlying ConTeXt doesn't like trying to put a combining accent on a character which doesn't ordinarily take the accent and thus doesn't have a pre-built composite character.

Comment: You can use hyphen followed by combining diaeresis: `-\utfchar{"0308}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hyphen followed by combining diaeresis, either directly inputting the UTF-8 characters or using the code point in `\utfchar`

```
\starttext
-̈

-\utfchar{"0308}
\stoptext
```

[image]